# Trying to build a JavaFX application... Exception in Application constructor

Tags: java, javafx

I was building a JavaFX application when, after some change, the code would no longer execute, instead giving the below error. I can't seem to isolate what change I made and was wondering if someone could explain this error and how to fix it.

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class space.invader.SpaceInvader
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ExpiringCache.get(ExpiringCache.java:78)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:406)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:215)
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getPermission(FileURLConnection.java:228)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getPermission(JarFileFactory.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getCachedJarFile(JarFileFactory.java:136)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:91)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.common.ImageTools.createInputStream(ImageTools.java:486)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(ImageStorage.java:311)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.loadAll(PrismImageLoader2.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.<init>(PrismImageLoader2.java:71)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.loadImage(QuantumToolkit.java:720)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.loadImage(Image.java:1065)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.initialize(Image.java:807)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:621)
    at space.invader.Tank.<init>(Tank.java:24)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:29)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
    at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
    at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
```

Comment: Without providing adequate minimal code to reproduce the error, I can only guess what the problem is. Looks like a stackoverflow. Your `AlienBlock` object contains a `SpaceInvader` which also contains an `AlienBlock`. When you create an `AlienBlock`, it also creates a `SpaceInvader` which in turn creates an `AlienBlock`, etc...in short your program was doomed to crash from the beginning. Try passing a reference to the first created `AlienBlock` to the `SpaceInvader` that is created after rather than creating a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by `StackOverflowError`, which most probably is a result in recursion

```
at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:29)
at space.invader.AlienBlock.<init>(AlienBlock.java:36)
at space.invader.SpaceInvader.<init>(SpaceInvader.java:30)
```

So, `SpaceInvader.<init>` method calls for `lienBlock.<init>` which in turn calls `SpaceInvader.<init>` and this completes an infinite loop of calls.
Take a look at thess lines and remove recursive calls, e.g. create an AlienBlock object without calling `SpaceInvader.<init>` within int